# Trying to install Django via Macports on Leopard

Tags: python, django

I have Python 2.6 & 3.1 installed on Leopard via mac ports with no problems. I want to install Django 1.2 via mac ports for Python 2.6, but a google search of how to do it seems to point me in the wrong direction. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks again.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do that. [Install](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/install/#intro-install) it directly from [source](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

Or better, use [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

```
easy_install django
```

Or even better, use [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) (and add [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/) as a bonus (and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) for more fun!)):

```
pip install django
```

Comment: Because thats not really flexible. Pip and virtualenv are the way to go. There's an uninstall with pip. And with virutalenv you can control which python libs and interpreter you want to use for each different project. Also note that Django doesn't work with python 3.1.

Comment: Agree with Etienne. I don't like MacPorts anyway, but it is most useful when you're installing things like PIL that need compiling. Django is a purely Python library and can be 'installed' by simply symlinking to it.

Comment: If you're going to install python from MacPorts, it makes sense to stick with MacPorts for django as well; certainly for more complicated packages like PIL.  There's really no need for virtualenv in that case, especially on OS X where python framework builds make it much easier to deal with multiple python installations, if that is a consideration.  But why make life more difficult?  One command should install django and all necessary dependencies.  `sudo port install py26-django`

Comment: Thank you Ned & Daniel.....Im working on the solutions you guys gave me today. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with this package?

```
$ port info py26-django
py26-django @1.2.1 (python, www)
Variants:             bash_completion, universal

Description:          Django is a high-level Python Web framework that
                      encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Homepage:             http://www.djangoproject.com

Library Dependencies: python26, py26-distribute
Platforms:            darwin
License:              unknown
Maintainers:          arthurk@macports.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Just "throw" the django tarball within the site-packages (dist-packages in py2.6+) and you are done. What for do you need macports etc, with a pure python library?

Comment: Thanks Lakshman. It should work the way you suggested but I believe my paths are not set up correctly. I am working to resolve it now. Thank you....